# Exporting notebook as html with images in SageMaker

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, export-to-pdf, nbconvert

When using sagemaker studio, I am attempted to export my notebook with images. The only option from the file>>save_and_export_as that functions is html, however the images created in the notebook are not rendered in the resulting html file. How can I fix this in Sagemaker Studio?

I selected the html option from file>>save_and_export_as and I expected an html file with images (but no images were rendered)

Comment: Are you trying to export a nb with a plot output or with an image from your local folder? If it's a plot, I can see the plot in my HTML output from Studio. If you're trying to add an image, you'll need an extension - https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/export_embedded/readme.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.